# "Could not find MyFirstApp.apk!" Error

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, apk

I don't understand really what's going on.  I followed the basic android "Hello World" program tutorial on Google's website.  I made basically no alteration to any code...  I just ran it...  and it's not running.  The following occurs in the console each time I run the program:

```
[2013-05-27 11:44:46 - MyFirstApp] ------------------------------
[2013-05-27 11:44:46 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2013-05-27 11:44:46 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2013-05-27 11:44:46 - MyFirstApp] Could not find MyFirstApp.apk!
```

So, what am I supposed to do?  Did I not install something correctly?  I thought I did, but it's a complicated installation so I'm not certain how to go about this.

If someone could just explain what the error message means...  that could help a ton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because there is no MyFirstApp.apk that the adb can upload in the simulator or device.
Just clean the application and build it again from **Project>Clean** and then **Project>Build All**. The MyFirstApp.apk will be created.

And then try to run your application.

Answer (score 9):

Your project is probably the library project.

Unselect "Is Library" in project's properties Android section.